# Tensorflow model can't use mixed precision

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, automatic-mixed-precision

I'm trying to create a 3D autoencoder (3D Unet without BatchNorm and skip connections) with `keras`.
When I train it with `tf.float32` it learns, but when I'm using mixed precision policy the training seems infinite.

I managed to reproduce error in colab.
Here is my code (I'm using tf 2.12.0 following the [installation of tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip)).

Is there something that I've missed?

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tqdm import tqdm

from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv3D, Conv3DTranspose
from tensorflow.keras import Model
from tensorflow.keras import mixed_precision

## Run if mixed precision

# policy = mixed_precision.Policy('mixed_float16')
# tf.keras.mixed_precision.set_global_policy(policy)
```

```
def autoencoder():
    inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape = (160, 192, 160, 1))
    #Encoder
    conv_1 = Conv3D(32, (3, 3, 3), padding='same', activation = 'relu')(inputs) 
    conv_2 = Conv3D(64, (3, 3, 3), padding='same', activation = 'relu')(conv_1) 
    dw_1 = Conv3D(64, (2, 2, 2), strides = (2, 2, 2), padding = 'valid')(conv_2)
    conv_3 = Conv3D(64, (3, 3, 3), padding='same', activation = 'relu')(dw_1)
    conv_4 = Conv3D(128, (3, 3, 3), padding='same', activation = 'relu')(conv_3)
    dw_2 = Conv3D(128, (2, 2, 2), strides = (2, 2, 2), padding = 'valid')(conv_4)
    conv_5 = Conv3D(128, (3, 3, 3), padding='same', activation = 'relu')(dw_2)
    conv_6 = Conv3D(128, (3, 3, 3), padding='same', activation = 'relu')(conv_5)
    dw_3 = Conv3D(256, (2, 2, 2), strides = (2, 2, 2), padding = 'valid')(conv_6)
    conv_7 = Conv3D(256, (3, 3, 3), padding='same', activation = 'relu')(dw_3)
    conv_8 = Conv3D(256, (3, 3, 3), padding='same', activation = 'relu')(conv_7)
    #Decoder
    up_1 = Conv3DTranspose(256, (2, 2, 2), strides = (2, 2, 2), padding = 'valid')(conv_8)
    conv_9 = Conv3D(256, (3, 3, 3), padding='same', activation = 'relu')(up_1)
    conv_10 = Conv3D(256, (3, 3, 3), padding='same', activation = 'relu')(conv_9)
    up_2 = Conv3DTranspose(128, (2, 2, 2), strides = (2, 2, 2), padding = 'valid')(conv_10)
    conv_11 = Conv3D(128, (3, 3, 3), padding='same', activation = 'relu')(up_2)
    conv_12 = Conv3D(128, (3, 3, 3), padding='same', activation = 'relu')(conv_11)
    up_3 = Conv3DTranspose(64, (2, 2, 2), strides = (2, 2, 2), padding = 'valid')(conv_12)
    conv_13 = Conv3D(64, (3, 3, 3), padding='same', activation = 'relu')(up_3)
    conv_14 = Conv3D(32, (3, 3, 3), padding='same', activation = 'relu')(conv_13)
    
    out = Conv3D(1, (1, 1, 1), padding='same', activation = 'sigmoid', dtype = tf.float32)(conv_14)
    
    
    
    return Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=[out])

AE = autoencoder()
```

```
## without mixed precision policy

irm = tf.ones((1,160,192,160,1), dtype = tf.float32)

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-4)

@tf.function
def train_step(irm):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        irm_reconstruction = AE(irm)
        loss_rec = tf.keras.losses.MeanAbsoluteError()(irm, irm_reconstruction)
    grads = tape.gradient(loss_rec, AE.trainable_variables)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, AE.trainable_weights))
    return loss_rec

G_L = []
for epoch in tqdm(range(1, 5)):
    L = train_step(irm)
    G_L.append(L)
    print(f'Epoch {epoch} - train_loss = {G_L[-1]}')
```

```
# with mixed precision policy

irm = tf.ones((1,160,192,160,1), dtype = tf.float32)

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-4)
optimizer = mixed_precision.LossScaleOptimizer(optimizer)

@tf.function
def train_step(irm):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        irm_reconstruction = AE(irm)
        loss_rec = tf.keras.losses.MeanAbsoluteError()(irm, irm_reconstruction)
        scaled_loss = optimizer.get_scaled_loss(loss_rec)
    scaled_gradients = tape.gradient(scaled_loss, AE.trainable_variables)
    grads = optimizer.get_unscaled_gradients(scaled_gradients)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, AE.trainable_weights))
    return loss_rec

G_L = []
for epoch in tqdm(range(1, 5)):
    L = train_step(irm)
    G_L.append(L)
    print(f'Epoch {epoch} - train_loss = {G_L[-1]}')
```